# OS X, Terminal: make the Help key simulate Ins

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-layout, midnight-commander

In OS X Terminal I've configured the <kbd>Home</kbd> (`Ctrl+A` = `\001`), <kbd>End</kbd> (`Ctrl+E` = `\005`), <kbd>Page Up</kbd> (`\033[5~`) and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> (`\033[6~`) keys, so I improved the Midnight Commander experience a lot.

But how do I get the <kbd>Help</kbd> key to act as the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key (to select the focused file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

According to [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080122065954390) MacWorld Hint, `\033[2~` is the keycode for <kbd>Ins</kbd>.

I am not sure if this is true for Linux, my terminal reports `^[[2~` (by running `cat` and pressing <kbd>Ins</kbd>), but a friend of mine who has a Mac used this hint, and had success.

## Solution

1. Open *Terminal.app*
2. Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> to open preferences
3. Go to the profile setup tab, and click on the profile you use
4. Open the edit keyboard bindings pane
5. Map <kbd>Help</kbd> to `\033[2~` (if you cannot bind help, bind some other key like <kbd>F12</kbd>)